# Loss of data in case of multiple consumers for redis messaging

Tags: java, redis, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

In My application am using multiple consumers for receiving messages from publisher of redis .But now issue is loss of data and duplicate data i mean multiple consumers receiving reeving same message .How can I solve this issue in redis? and also can provide example in java am new to redis messaging.Please help me.

Here is my receiver

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledRecevierService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Bean
    RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        LOGGER.info("in redisConnectionFactory");
        JedisConnectionFactory redis = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        redis.setHostName("ipaddress");
        redis.setPort(6379);
        return redis;
    }

    @Bean
    StringRedisTemplate template(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        LOGGER.info("in template");
        return new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory);
    } 

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void getScheduledMessage() {

        StringRedisTemplate template = template(redisConnectionFactory());
        System.out.println("The time is now " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        LOGGER.info("Sending messages...");

        String message = template.opsForList().leftPop("point-to-point-test"); // latch.await();
        // template.convertAndSend("chat", "Hello from Redis! count: " + i);
        LOGGER.info("Got  message " + message + " from chat1 channel"); //
    }

}
```

I am running this applications in multiple consumer instances.My Queue "point-to-point-test" having 1000 messages what i observed is in multiple server logs reading same message.

Can we implement point to point protocol communication in redis using java?

RPOPLPUSH command in redis solve this issue?if yes post some example in java.

from fast few days am struggled  to fix these issues in redis messaging please help me

Comment: Try to show own investigations.

Answer (score 0):

Use redis transactions to ensure that all your commands are executed sequentially http://redis.io/topics/transactions

Use Jedis as the java client library , see its test for usage on transactions https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/commands/TransactionCommandsTest.java

Comment: My issue is with multiple consumers only in case of single it is working fine.But if i use multiple consumers some of the messages are missing and same message is reading by the multiple consumers?

Comment: Are you using any client library or you have written the code to execute redis command ? Use Jedis to write your consumer and then see if you still face issues

Comment: As such commands in redis are atomic, so when a consumer does LPOP it will get an item removed from the list and no other consumer shall get that item. You should not be seeing any duplicates. Try writing your consumers only in jedis , do not use spring data and see.